# Where can I find closed dates for the New York Stock Exchange for the coming year?

Tags: stock-exchanges

Does the NYSE have the same holiday/closed dates as the CME? Where can I find the holiday schedule for the coming year?

Comment: A more general solution... [NYSE Holidays 2016](https://www.google.com/search?q=NYSE+holidays+2016)

Answer (score 3):

The NYSE holidays are listed online here:

https://www.nyse.com/markets/hours-calendars

Answer (score 1):

You can find the NYSE holiday dates listed on the exchange's own site (already linked in answer above), which should obviously be consulted as the most reliable source; they are also published in an article that I have written here: [NYSE Holidays 2016](http://bestbrokerdeals.com/nyse-holidays-2016-schedule/), which provides additional information about traditions and events that can be expected to lead to unscheduled closures, and closed dates for holidays that are day-of-month rather than date specific (e.g. President's Day and Memorial Day).

NYSE Holidays are not quite identical to those for the Chicago Mercantile Exchange, though most US stock exchange dates are the same. Also, note that both the Merc (via the Globex platform) and NYSE Arca have different normal cash sessions and trading hours to the New York Stock Exchange.